# read excel file that need to skip row and footer with dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I need to read a high number of excel file into bigquery from google cloud storage. Each of these file needs to have the skiprows and skipfooter arguments.
I am thinking about using DataFlow. However I have no idea how to proceed

What I have attempted

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Read all the startups')
   parser.add_argument('--output_prefix', default='/tmp/output', help='Output prefix')
   parser.add_argument('--input', default='gs://{folder_of_input}', help='Input directory')

   options, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()
   p = beam.Pipeline(argv=pipeline_args)

   input = '{0}*.xlsx'.format(options.input)
   output_prefix = options.output_prefix

   # find most used packages
   (p
      | 'getExcel' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(input, skiprows=8, skipfooter=2)
      | 'write' >> beam.io.WriteToText(output_prefix)
   )

   p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

Comment: Hi @le Minh Nguyen, There are no skiprows and skipfooter parameters available in Dataflow. For your requirement, you can use [skip_header_lines](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.textio.html) to skip the number of header lines. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar, skip_header_lines can imitate skiprows, but what about skipfooter?

I Found the method beam.dataframe.io.read_excel that has the method that I am interested in. However I cannot seem to read multiple files with this. I receive the error "skipfooter cannot be used in iteration"

Comment: If you know what your footer looks like in advance, you could remove it from the collection by implementing a function that detects it, and then using `beam.Filter`. Inefficient, but possible.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a DoFn that consumes each individual excel file in Python. You can do something like this:

```py
p
| fileio.MatchFiles(options.input)
| ParDo(ConsumeExcelFiles())
```

Where your DoFn is:

```py
class ConsumeExcelFiles(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, filename):
    import openpyxl
    local_filename = self._download_from_gcs(filename)
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(local_filename)
    # Now you process the excel workbook
```

Does this help?